# How can I pin pidgin window to a part of my screen space?

Tags: windows-xp, pidgin

so that if I maximize any other window I can still see the pidgin window where I pinned it and the other Window just takes up the rest of the space.

I am using Windows XP. I think it should be a Pigdin plugin or something but cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I have found the option you seem to be looking for.

Select: **Tools -> Plugins**

Scroll down the list and find the plugin: **Windows Pidgin Options**

Put a check mark beside this plugin, then click on the **Configure Plugin** button

On the configuration window, there is a section called **Buddy List** which should give you the option of making your buddy list a **Dockable Buddy List**, which allows you to pin the buddy list to one edge of the screen, and a dropdown of options for **Keep Buddy List on Top**. I have the dropdown set to **Only when docked** on my system.

Comment: This was helpful, although I was looking for how to unpin pidgin

Comment: I set "Keep Buddy List on Top" to "Never" so that the drop shadow on Windows 7 doesn't go over maximized windows.